# What flour is best for diabetic person?

Tags: diabetes, health-education

What type of flour is most effective at controlling blood sugar levels in diabetics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this article [20 Healthy Flours from Lowest to Highest Carbohydrates](https://www.thediabetescouncil.com/20-healthy-flours/), whole grain or "flour from nut and plant sources that are low in carbohydrates".

The whole grain helps to lower the glycemic index (GI), meaning that sugars are released more slowly.  Whereas the non grain flours have are  lower in carbohydrate, meaning less will be converted to sugars.

Top 5 listed are

1. Walnut Flour
2. Almond Flour
3. Ground Flaxseed
4. Soy Flour
5. Spelt Flour